# How can I delete my Math Overflow account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is there any way that I could delete my Math Overflow account? I cannot find anything about leaving one of StackExchange communities neither in my Stack Exchange profile page, nor in Math Overflow profile page. I've joined it accidentally.

I saw the [StackOverflow.com account deletion page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account), but I do not want to delete StackOverflow account, I simply want to leave Math Overflow community. There is no `delete` button next to `edit` in my MathOverflow profile page:

[image]

Comment: searching "delete account" in the help center goes to http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: There is no 'delete' button next to 'edit' in the community page. I do not want to delete Stackoverflow.com account.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are asking. Which account *do* you want to delete?

Comment: Then keep reading the help page where it tells you to use the Contact form. (You should probably also be asking this on that site's Meta if you don't want to delete your Stack Overflow account...)

Comment: @ChrisF I've joined mathoverflow.com community, I didn't now that this community is not for beginers (math.stackexchange.com is). I want to leave the mathoverflow.com community.

Comment: @niekas- go to your profile on MathOverflow and there should be a "delete" button there.

Comment: @Wooble I tried filling the Account deletion form 'What can we help you?' -> 'I need to delete my user profile'. 'You profile link' -> my mathoverflow.com user page and it frows an error, that the profile link is not valid.

Comment: I see you say it did not work but perhaps try it from here http://mathoverflow.net/help/deleting-account There might be a check sensistive to the origin of the click.

Comment: @quid Thank you.

Comment: To follow up on the above: when I click that my MathOverflow profile page is given automatically. So if you clicked on the link given above which is for SO rather than MO and then tweaked it I can see how things might have gotten messed up. (You are welcome hope it helps)

Answer (score 7):

A subsidiary question: What are the consequences of an account deletion? Are all that user's votes, +/-, over all history, removed? Are all their comments, answers, questions, removed? Presumably not questions that have answers. Presumably not comments that might be embedded in a comment thread.

Just curious. I am sure StackExchange has figured out reasonable rules...

Comment: If the user has only a few votes (where few is not public knowledge), then the votes are removed; if the user has voted, say, several thousand posts, then these votes are kept by transferring them to the Community user. Negative scored posts are deleted, and comments and non-negative posts are kept with the unlinkable "userXXX" identifier rather than the user name with a link to their profile.

Comment: Thanks, @AsafKaragila!

Answer (score 5):

Your MathOverflow account is scheduled for deletion in 24 hours or so.